# Styling iframe with specific url

Tags: jquery, css, iframe

is there a way to add a styling to an iframe only if it has a specific src? or to add a class to it only with specific src?

I am working with an iframe with dynamic urls, and only want certain urls to be styled differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use attribute selectors to style it a certain way.

```
iframe[src$="whatever.com"] {
...
}
```

For more info on attribute selectors see here: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/css3attributeselectors

Answer (score 0):

```
$(IFRAME_SELECTOR).get(0).contentWindow.location
```

If it matches apply the styles.